# How to send an array using QWebSocket?

Tags: arrays, node.js, qt, websocket

I created a client-server system including:

- a node.js server (with module ws);
- a WebClient;
- a QtClient (using Qt5.4 and QWebSocket).

The QtClient sends and receives strings via the method `QWebSocket.sendTextMessage (QString s)`. How can I send an array of strings?

---

OTHER INFO:

The WebClient sends an array using JSON:

```
# index.html (WebClient)
    socket.onopen = function() {  
        var array = {
            value1: "WebClient value1 = v1", 
            value2: "WebClient value2 = v2"
        };
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(array), {binary: true, mask: false}); 
};

# server.js
socket.on('connection', function(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    var array = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(array["value1"]);
    console.log( array["value2"]);
  });
});

# console node
C:\Users\PietroP\Desktop\cs\v0.3>node server.js
Server connect on http://192.168.1.60:3000/
a user connected
WebClient value1 : v1
WebClient value2 : v2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWebSocket class does not have direct implementation for sending arrays. You can send binary or text messages. For details please refer to:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html

Here is an alternative approach:

You can convert your array into a long string using something like

```
str = array.toString() // This is psuedo code
```

in a loop and send from the sender side. Then on the receiver side you can get parse it using a method such as

```
str.split(...);
```

Hope that heps!

Edit: You've probably already noticed that: in your sample code what JSON.stringify(array) and JSON.parse(message) do is nothing but converting array to string and then parse the string into array again.

Comment: Great! Simple but effective solution! I thought you could send complex structures, but that's okay! :)

Thanks again!

Comment: @Athair: Glad to hear that :) I appreciate an upvote to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". :(
I'll do it as soon as possible!